# How to configure Persistent Cookies with ADFS 2.0

Tags: session, cookies, saml, adfs, persistent

I am running a Lab environment with Windows Server 2008 R2 and ADFS 2.0. I am also running Cisco Unified Communications Manager 10.5.1 (CUCM) and Jabber for Windows 10.5.2 which work with SAML 2.0.

When I go to the CUCM web page, I get redirected to the ADFS Forms Based Authentication page where I can authenticate with my AD credentials. I can then login to the web page fine. When I close the web page and re-open it, I am re-directed to the ADFS FBA page once more.

From my understanding, there are two types of cookies in SAML; Session and Persistent. I am also of the understanding that Session cookies are limited to a single browser instance and do not survive exiting the browser while Persistent cookies are available to all browser instances and expire after a set time.

My questions are:

1. Is my above understanding correct WRT Session v. Persistent cookies?
2. Are Persistent cookies enabled by default in ADFS 2.0 or do they have to be enabled?
3. If already enabled, why does the above scenario happen? (looks like to me that only Session cookies are being used)

Thanks,
Daniel

Comment: can you check the cockie your getting from ADFS and check the expiration

Comment: Hey Stefan, could you let me know how to check the cookie? Are there any powershell commands to check?